# show multiple status messages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css, telerik

I have requirement where i show multiple status on the screen and Based on the application status i need to color that status. If the status is completed then i need to color green, if its in Progress i need to color the status in Blue and if that status is not complete then it would be in grey color. What is the best way to achieve this. Are there any controls in asp.net or Telerik to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What are you using for your status boxes?

Comment: I can use labels to show status and achieve that. But was wondering is  there any better way to do this or are there any asp.net or Telerik controls to achieve that.

Comment: I would just use labels, I'm not sure about Telerik, but I doubt there's a more efficient way than labels with ASP.NET

Comment: Just set the CSS for each label depending on your criteria. You don't need anything special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use css

First write css classes:

```
.completed
{
background-color: Green;
color:White; /* set height/width of box as you want */
}
.inprocess
{
background-color:Blue;
color: White;
}
```

.. so on

in your asp.net page put a div as

```
<div id="info" runat="server"> </div>
```

in code-behind

```
if(completed) // your condition
{ 
 info.Attributes.Add("class", "completed");
 info.InnerText = "Completed";
}
// so ....
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Telerik, there is the `Gauge` control were you can specify colors of different levels, in your case the levels are completion levels.

```
<telerik:RadLinearGauge runat="server" ID="RadLinearGauge1" Width="150px" Height="350px">
                    <Pointer Shape="BarIndicator" Value="15">
                         <Track Opacity="0.2" />
                    </Pointer>
                    <Scale Min="-20" Max="50" MajorUnit="10">
                         <Labels Format="{0} degrees" />
                         <Ranges>
                              <telerik:GaugeRange Color="#2a94cb" From="-20" To="5" />
                              <telerik:GaugeRange Color="#8dcb2a " From="5" To="17" />
                              <telerik:GaugeRange Color="#ffc700" From="17" To="27" />
                              <telerik:GaugeRange Color="#ff7a00" From="27" To="35" />
                              <telerik:GaugeRange Color="#c20000" From="35" To="50" />
                         </Ranges>
                    </Scale>
               </telerik:RadLinearGauge>
```

Ref: [Telerik RadLinearGauge](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/gauge/examples/types/lineargauge/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: but that does not address my scenario. Thanks for Info though.